# How to retrieve last ran queries with username

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently had a problem with some query that massively updated one of my tables and I'm trying to discover what could possibly gone wrong.

I need to know if there is any way to retrieve last ran queries with at least username, and if possibly the @Parameters values.

I searched a lot on the web and found some solutions like:

```
SELECT 
    c.session_id, s.host_name, s.login_name, s.status, 
    st.text, s.login_time, s.program_name, *
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_connections c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS st
WHERE
    text LIKE '%YOURPROCHERE%'
ORDER BY 
    last_read desc

SELECT        
    SQLTEXT.text, STATS.last_execution_time, *
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats STATS
CROSS APPLY   
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(STATS.sql_handle) AS SQLTEXT
WHERE
    STATS.last_execution_time > GETDATE()-1
    AND sqltext.text LIKE '%YOURPROCHERE%'
ORDER BY      
    STATS.last_execution_time DESC
```

But none of those statements helped me out, they didn't returned any results that matches the hour of the error.

I found one query that matches the run hour with my problem and the exact query text that was run. But it does not show me the user and I can't figure out how to look for the username based on the table.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(s2.objectid),'Ad-Hoc') AS ProcName,
         execution_count,s2.objectid, s1.sql_handle, 
         s1.plan_handle, s1.query_plan_hash,
         (SELECT TOP 1 
              SUBSTRING(s2.TEXT,statement_start_offset / 2+1 ,
              ((CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
                       THEN (LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),s2.TEXT)) * 2)
                       ELSE statement_end_offset 
                END) - statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1)) AS sql_statement,
         last_execution_time
     FROM 
         sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1
     CROSS APPLY 
         sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 
    ) x
WHERE 
    sql_statement NOT like 'SELECT COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(s2%' AND sql_statement like '%YOURQUERYHERE%'
--and OBJECTPROPERTYEX(x.objectid,'IsProcedure') = 1
ORDER BY 
    last_execution_time DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy way to find the person who ran the query this far after the fact.  Your best bet is to put a trigger on the table that will log the username of the session user whenever they make an update.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I do not managed to figure it out yesterday and now the logs are all gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking in the SQL Blackbox Trace that is enabled by default.  It captures some of the previous queries executed on the server.  It does have a limit and on a busy production server, it's often limited to minutes of data.

```
DECLARE @filename nvarchar(512);  
SELECT @filename = CAST(value as nvarchar(512))FROM fn_trace_getinfo(1) where property = 2; 
SELECT * FROM
fn_trace_gettable (@filename, DEFAULT) WHERE TextData IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I hate this!  SO won't let me post code.  I keep getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I do not managed to figure it out yesterday and now the logs are all gone.